# Inductive formula involving parity

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(b_n)_n$ be the sequence defined by $b_1=b_2=1$ and the inductive formula:

$$\begin{cases}
 b_{2n} & = b_n \\
 b_{2n+1} & = b_n + b_{n+1}
\end{cases}$$

I am to find a simple expression of this sequence.

---

I've tried defining $V_n = \begin{pmatrix} b_n \\ b_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}$ and therefore getting:

$$\begin{cases}
 V_{2n} = \begin{pmatrix} b_n \\ b_n+b_{n+1} \end{pmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} V_n  = M_0 V_n\\
 V_{2n+1} = \begin{pmatrix} b_n+b_{n+1} \\ b_{n+1} \end{pmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} V_n = M_1 V_n
\end{cases}$$

Thus, if $n=n_0+...+n_p2^p$, then $V_n = M_{n_{p-1}}...M_{n_0} V_1$.

I don't think this helps very much other than formalizing the problem. These matrices don't commute and their product has no simple expression short of calculation $b_n$ explicitly.

I don't really know where to go from here.

---

**EDIT**: after a bit of research, it's a [well-known sequence](https://oeis.org/A002487) (thanks to Hw Chu). It doesn't seem to have a simple expression, but I did find out:

$$b_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} ({k \choose n-k-1} \mod 2)$$

This is what I am now trying to prove.

Comment: So ... $b_3 = b_{2\cdot1+1} = b_1+b_{1-1}=b_1+b_0=1+...$? What is $b_0$?

Comment: By looking at the computations, I think it is $b_{2n+1} = b_n + b_{n+1}$  instead?

Comment: I am sorry, you are right about that mistake. $b_0$ is not defined, it starts at 1.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A002487

Comment: Hmm so what I gather from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SternsDiatomicSeries.html) is that there are no simple expressions other than that sum, I'll look into it...

Comment: The formula can apparently be attributed to L.Carlitz according to [this](https://hrcak.srce.hr/file/1591).